# In SQLAlchemy efficiently find chidless parents

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a `Worker` table and a `Task` table where many tasks can be associated to a worker (but same task cannot belong to many workers).

I get a list of finished tasks that are/were deleted from the DB.
I would like to find all the workers that do not have any tasks (and delete from the DB).

Currently I loop over the workers and ask each how many tasks they have and at the end I delete those with no tasks. This is inefficient.
Is there a way to do this with a *single* query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. Make sure to add an index to `task.worker_id`. The SQL would look like

```sql
SELECT id
FROM worker
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT FROM task
  WHERE worker_id = worker.id
)
```

and in SQLAlchemy, depending on your code of course

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
has_any_tasks = sa.exists(
  sa.select([])
  .select_from(Task)
  .where(Task.worker_id == Worker.id)
)


# If you use SQLAlchemy core
workers_without_tasks = sa.select([Worker.id]).where(~has_any_tasks)

# Equivalent if you use the ORM
workers_without_tasks = session.query(Worker).filter(~has_any_tasks)
```